# Problem connecting to svn

Tags: svn, virtualbox

I'm trying to connect to a svn server where I have some documents. The problem is that I'm getting the next error:

**"Could not open the requested SVN filesystem"**

What's happening? I'm using Tortoise SVN but I get that error in the browser too...

What can it be?

I don't know if this could affect but, I'm trying to connect throught a virtual SO (using virtualbox). I'm telling this because in my main SO (not virtual) I can connect succesfully to the svn, but with virtual box don't.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced this error before and it turned out that the user account I'm using doesn't have the appropriate privilege to access the folder in the server where Subversion stores its files. You need to make sure that the user account that you're using has read/write access to the actual Subversion server.

Comment: @lan The user account is correct. I check it because in another pc it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with the apache config and the file system.  Check the apache error log and the `SVNPath` or `SVNParentPath` settings in the apache conf.

`grep -r SVNPa /etc/httpd`

That's the typical location of the config files for RHEL/CentOS/Fedora.  Could also be in `/etc/apache2`

Comment: I forget to say that i'm using Windows 7. But it really could be Svn config? Browser is crashing too.

Comment: yes, if the server cannot access the subversion file system it is most definitely a server config issue.  The apache error logs usually have a more informative message.

Comment: but it works well in my Windows 7. But in my Windows xp (in the virtual SO), doesnt work.

Comment: so different clients hitting the same server?  one client says it's ok and the other complains it could not open the requested file system?  what output do you see in the access and error log while making the failed request? how about a good request?